# Updated images in assets folder not showing on launching app

Tags: android

is it possible to update assets folder on every update of app.I make a quiz app and it has images on assets folder.Number of images on folder shows when i launch the app.But when i update images on assets folder say from 10-20 images the actual total number of images to be shown on app is 20 but i still see 10 images.But when i uninstall and install app i do see all 20 images.how to updated assets folder without uninstalling app?

```
String[] getImagesFromAssets() {
    String[] img_files = null;

    try {
        img_files = getAssets().list("pictures");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GameActivity.class
                .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return img_files;
}

void loadImage(String name) {
    try {
        InputStream ims = getAssets().open("pictures/" + name);

        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        image.setImageDrawable(d);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Discarding any expections is a bad practice. Will get you in trouble most times.

Comment: @BinoyBabu pardon.can you help me to find a solution to this?

Comment: Use `catch(IOException ioe) { ioe.printStackTrace(); }` to get more debug info and post the trace here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Assets folder of android application will be initialized once at the time of installation only. You cannot update the assets folder after the application has been packaged and installed.  After installation if you do any changes in the resources it will not reflect to your older installed version.As Asset folder is read only , you cannot write or update any file present there.

If you want to update it then you need to uninstall the older version and install new version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.i see.i read this some where to while i googled for this.btw i would like to what what is the alternate way to retrieve images,since assets do not update unless users uninstall app?also can i use drawable folder to add images ie drawable/new_folder and would like to know a way to retrieve from that new_folder replacing my assets code which i shared above.

Comment: The only way is you copy your images into the SDCard and then try to access it from there. As the drawable folders are also read only If you keep your image into drawable then you can not update it at runtime by adding images into it. So its always better to copy your images into some external storage and then access it from there in your application which is feasible way.

Comment: oh i see.so can you provide code if possible.btw just curious how other quiz app work?do you have any idea?ie adding more levels to game.

Comment: @GovindNarayan Here you will get numbers of result for copying the assets files and folder into sdcard. https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr#q=android%20how%20to%20copy%20files%20in%20'assets'%20to%20sdcard

Comment: Thankyou.i will go through it ;)

Comment: btw if assets been copied from app to sd card can i retrieve it on same app from sd card location?if so how?

Comment: Post another question regarding your queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to take image from assets:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream istr = null;
            try {
                istr = assetManager.open(strName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
```

Comment: i believe this is what i used instead of assigning object name to getAssets();